# What should the [windows] tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, tags

I was going through tags to create one-line details when possible and came up with a problem with [windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows).

Question for Microsoft Windows as well as GUI windows are being tagged on this. So should a new tag [microsoft-windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-windows) be added to the site and questions retagged?

Comment: Should be noted that the tag wiki has been updated since this question was asked, to "Microsoft's well-known operating system. **Use this tag for code reviews where the code is targeted specifically for this platform, when no other more specific tags exist**."

Comment: @retailcoder: I've just revisited [windows] and retagged as necessary.  I didn't create any new tags, but used [console] in place of [windows] where needed.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting observation, and I agree. Let's see if others feel the same. I think [windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) should be synonymized, which would do all the retagging. Otherwise, we'll still have both [windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [microsoft-windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-windows), which is redundant. I'd go with [gui-windows](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-windows), as you've mentioned.